# Как во fragment поверх RecyclerView поместить кнопку?

Tags: android, recyclerview, button

В Activity есть fragment внутри которого есть RecyclerView, нужно, чтобы поверх RecyclerView в правом нижнем углу располагалась кнопка и чтобы при скроллинге экрана она оставалась на месте(по нажатию этой кнопки происходить переход на другое Activity).

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.fragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="91dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте после `RecyclerView` вашу кнопку, я думаю вам нужен FAB, но это не главное

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="GO!"
    android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

Если надо вплотную к углу, уберите строчку с `layout_margin`

Answer (score 2):

Примерно как то так. Использовать свойство FrameLayout размещать виджеты слоями :

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.fragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="91dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Еще до кучи. С использованием `ConstraintLayout`, хотя в данной разметке его использование так же мало оправдано, как и `RelativeLayout`, так как `FrameLayout` намного легче их обоих, что положительно скажется на оптимизации

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Фрейм размещает View по порядку друг за другом, поэтому кнопка будет над списком

Comment: Так же замените gravity на layout_gravity. К тому же фрейм не обязателен, хватит и просто Relative

Comment: @Flippy да, я по памяти писал. FrameLayout во много легче RelativeLayout и в этой разметке нет ничего, что бы оправдывало  использование более тяжелого контейнера

Comment: По сути верно, релатив позволяет располагать вью с более широким ассортиментом и здесь его юзейж является неоправданным